# Erro compiling with boost

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm getting this error:

```
  CXX      luascript.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:15:0,
                 from luascript.cpp:21:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp:16:5: error: #error Compiling Filesystem version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
 #   error Compiling Filesystem version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
     ^
make[1]: *** [luascript.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/src.DEB'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've compiled this before and I dont recall having seen this.

Line 21 of luascript.cpp is `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`

What can I do to fix this?

I'm on Debian 7 using latest packages and gcc 4.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LUA library requires a - now obsolete - older version of Boost Filesystem.

This was [changed in boost 1.50.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/release_history.html):

> Remove Filesystem Version 2 from the distribution. Version 3 is now the only distributed version. Those still using V2 are urged to migrate to V3 as soon as possible.

Note, boost 1.50.0 was released on *June 28th, 2012 12:48 GMT*.

So, urge your library supplier to migrate to V3 :)